# How to model if-then?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-variable, logical-constraints

$i$ is a set $1$ to $n$.

$j$ is a set $1$ to $m$.

$j$ and $k$ are from the same set such that $j\neq k$.

$c_{ij}$ is a parameter.

$x_{ij}$ is a binary variable.

How to model: If
$$c_{ij}\cdot x_{ij} \ge c_{ik}, \forall i,j,k,j\neq k$$ then $$x_{ij} \ge x_{ik}, \forall i,j,k,j\neq k$$

The goal is to select $x_{ij}$ with the highest coefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your quantifiers are misplaced and you instead want to enforce
$$\bigwedge_{i,j,k,j\neq k} \left(c_{ij}x_{ij} \ge c_{ik} \implies x_{ij} \ge x_{ik}\right)$$
Equivalently,
$$\bigwedge_{i,j,k,j\neq k} \left(x_{ij} < x_{ik} \implies c_{ij}x_{ij} < c_{ik} \right)$$
$$\bigwedge_{i,j,k,j\neq k} \left(\lnot x_{ij} \land x_{ik} \implies c_{ij}x_{ij} < c_{ik} \right)$$
Introduce constants $\epsilon > 0$ and $M_{ijk} = \max(c_{ij},0) - c_{ik} + \epsilon$ and binary variable $y_{ijk}$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
(1 - x_{ij}) + x_{ik} - 1 &\le y_{ijk} \tag1\label1 \\
c_{ij}x_{ij} - c_{ik} + \epsilon &\le M_{ijk}(1 - y_{ijk}) \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces
$\lnot x_{ij} \land x_{ik} \implies y_{ijk}$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces
$y_{ijk} \implies c_{ij}x_{ij}+ \epsilon \le c_{ik}$.

---

From your last sentence, maybe what you really want is much simpler:
$$x_{ij} \ge x_{ik} \quad \text{for all $i,j,k$ such that $j \not= k$ and $c_{ij} > c_{ik}$}$$

Comment: Yes, your are right in your last sentence with a small change: $c_{ij} \ge c_{ik}$. What do you think is the way to achieve it? Is there a simpler way? I am sorry if I caused a confusion, I do not have a deep knowledge in logical constraints.

Comment: In that case, the conditions depend on known constants, so you can express the constraint directly as $x_{ij} \ge x_{ik}$ with the specified conditions in the index set for the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand if $c_{ij}>c_{ik}$ then when $x_{ij}>= {c_{ik}\over c_{ij}}$ implies $x_{ij} = 1$ as ${c_{ik}\over c_{ij}}$ will be $[0,1]$. So in that case $x_{ij}>=x_{ik}$ is obvious and moot as $x_{ij}$ is binary and will be 1.
Game begins if ${c_{ik}\over c_{ij}} < 0$.
Then $x_{ij}$ can be $0$ or $1$. If $x_{ij}=0$ then need to ensure $x_{ik}=0$.
So introduce M (just big enough, say slightly larger than $\lvert{c_{ik}\over c_{ij}}\rvert$ and introduce a constraint
$x_{ik} <= {M+ {c_{ik}\over c_{ij}}\over M}$.
This ensures if ${c_{ik}\over c_{ij}} <0$ then $x_{ik} < 1$ and hence is $0$.